# TimeoutException when using Blazemeter HTTP2 Sampler in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, http2, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

I'm using the Blazemeter HTTP2 JMeter Sampler in JMeter and have the following issue.

```
021-03-07 09:29:03,996 ERROR c.b.j.h.s.HTTP2SampleResult: Error while await for response
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1886) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2021) ~[?:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Connection.awaitResponses(HTTP2Connection.java:171) ~[jmeter-bzm-http2-1.6.1.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.lambda$waitAllResponses$1(HTTP2Request.java:585) ~[jmeter-bzm-http2-1.6.1.jar:?]
    at java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:976) [?:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.waitAllResponses(HTTP2Request.java:583) [jmeter-bzm-http2-1.6.1.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.threadFinished(HTTP2Request.java:546) [jmeter-bzm-http2-1.6.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:775) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:993) [jorphan.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:976) [jorphan.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadFinished(JMeterThread.java:742) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:328) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

It only happens when the payload is about 250kb and when about 120 to 400 requests per 30 seconds are conducted. In this case about 70% of the requests fail!
Less reqeusts work fine 100%. 500 requests with about 10kb payload work fine also. It makes no difference if timeout is set or not.

Comment: not only 250kb but when making test runs with many and large requests

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's the plugin or JMeter issue, most probably your server gets overloaded hence cannot provide the valid response in timely fashion.

1. Check your server logs
2. Ensure that the server has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, Network, etc. It can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)
3. Consider adding a [ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) and correlate successful and failed requests using i.e. [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) chart, it might be the case you're hitting the bottleneck and you need to precisely identify the time stamp and the payload size/number of requests which are causing the problem